# Playing Munchkin with only 2 players

Tags: munchkin

I'm looking into playing Munchkin with only two players. According to the box and the rules the game was made for a minimum of 3 players (probably for good reasons), but I haven't been able yet to understand what specific aspect it is that implies this minimum. What are the limitations of playing with only two players that make the game unplayable with it's current rules set?